# Custom node editor

Tags: vb.net, tree, nodes

I'm sorry if this question seems a little bit broad.

I'm writing fairly complex data processing software/script. In order to account for all the possible setting configurations, I feel like I need something like a node editor for the UI. (Something like this: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img534/5957/ucjg.png)
Depending on the connected nodes and their sequence, different functions and in different order would be used to process the input data.

I know, there is quite a number of options, but the thing is, I'm a newbie in most languages, so I ask for advice:
What would be best/easiest/fastest way to approach this?

I've written my code mostly in vb.net, so examples in vb or something similar would be greatly appreciated.

If necessary, I'd learn a new language, but i need recommendations on what language should I pick up. Something fairly easy, so I wouldn't be spending months on designing the interface.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: There is no available visual editor for Node.js. If you really need to program for Node.js, you **must** learn Javascript. My personal tip for a beginner is [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org) or Codecademy. For designing your website, HTML + CSS is my personal tip. It is really simple and fast to learn. But if you know VB.NET, why don't you do your website using ASP.NET, too? Well these are realistic options.

Comment: Thank You for your answer.
A little clarification. It's not a website. So it doesn't necessarily need to be a javascript/html. This node editor will go in my application as a user interface/settings input tool.
If I do the html version, I'd need to somehow transfer the node connection configuration to my vb.net application (I imagine, that could be done via some sort of save file, which is then read by my application), but maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Before you start imagining a lot of stuff, I recommend you to start learning Javascript. This can be done in 5 minutes creating a GET request on the desired path. For example, <server>:8080/transferConnection?connection=<my node connection>

Comment: And repeating, there is no available visual UI editor of Node.js/Javascript. For doing these settings, you can use the Javascript localStorage API.

Comment: Though, I don't feel like we're on the same page exactly.
Anyway. Thank You! I'll look into javascript.